# React-bootstrap: cannot set up navbar

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I do not get an error but there is no styling, I do not see the navbar items and instead of the hamburger icon I see an empty button (on a wide and narrow screen):
[image]

My jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Navbar, Nav, NavItem} from 'react-bootstrap';

class NavbarPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
          <Navbar default collapseOnSelect>
            <Navbar.Header>
              <Navbar.Brand>
              </Navbar.Brand>
              <Navbar.Toggle/>
            </Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Collapse>
              <Nav pullRight>
                <NavItem eventKey={1} componentClass={Link}  to="/home">
                  Home
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey={2} componentClass={Link}  to="/about">
                  About
                </NavItem>
              </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </Navbar>
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I was linking to bootstrap4 in my public index.html, but after linking it to bootstrap 3:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And also removing the bootstrap4 link, now the navbar looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I assume you haven't put this code to the index.html on the project: <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: Thanks I was indeed linking to bootstrap 4, but now when using your link it looks different but still with no styling at all. I edited the question to show. btw, it's impossible to use react-bootstrap in combination with bootstrap4 library with its normal html syntax?